# JQuery Selector copy text from div and place in span

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I need some JQuery selector help...

My HTML is

```
<div id="Manager"><span>LastName, FirstName (UK)</span></div>

<span id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_4118aa1d_2690_4da8_b2b2_dc1943e73968_LineManager/>
```

I need to select the text from the div Manager and copy that into the span which contains the text LineManager.

I have the selector for the span which contains the text 'LineManager'

```
$("span[id*='LineManager']")
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to select the text from the div
>   Manager and copy that into the span
>   which contains the text LineManager.

This should do it:

```
$("span[id*='LineManager']").text($('#Manager').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("span[id*='LineManager']").html = $('#Manager span').html
```

Edit: Oops, it should have been

```
$("span[id*='LineManager']").html($('#Manager span').html)
```

as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var span_text = $("div#Manager span");
$("span[id*='LineManager']").text(span_text);
```

I would recommend if possible, adding a non-dynamic class (for increased reliability) to the span element with the really long id. So your html ends up somenthing like this.

```
<div id="Manager"><span class="target-js">LastName, FirstName (UK)</span></div>    
<span class="fill-js" id="dynamicallyGeneratedString"/>
```

Then you can do a more maintainable:

```
var span_text = $("span.target-js");
$('span.fill-js').text(span_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe

```
var managerText = $("#Manager span").html();
$("span[id*='LineManager']").html(managerText);
```

Though the `[id*=]` attribute selector is not very efficient, so if you can figure out some other way of identifying your line manager you may see better performance.  I typically like class based selectors for this, but I'm not sure if that is something you can add to your LineManager span or not.

Answer (score 0):

### JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $("span[id*='LineManager']").html($("#Manager > span").html());
        }); 
    });
```

---

### HTML:

```
    <div id="Manager"><span>LastName, FirstName (UK)</span></div>
    <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_4118aa1d_2690_4da8_b2b2_dc1943e73968_LineManager"></span>
    <input type="button" id="button">
```